# How safely to send signal between logic and higher current pcb?

Tags: pcb, mosfet, signal, ground-loop

I'm designing a PCB with 4 FETs. These are driven in the same board by totem pole drivers, and their load are about 5A total. I am using PWM at 1000Hz.

The signal comes from a logic IC in another board. Is there a safe way to avoid loops and noise without using optocouplers?

The current scheme I am using is:

Logic board to Buffer PCB = 4 signal wires.
And each board has its own connection to the PSU. (GND and 12V)
The distance is going to be ~20cm max in what I think will be a noisy environment.

Comment: How many power boards? Are all of the power boards physically located close by each other?

Comment: 2 power boards per logic board. There will be more than a logic board. Everything is in a 15cm radius, loads are ~3meters away though. Has to be made in a rush without knowing final amounts of channels, hence the modularity and multiples..

Comment: LVDS drivers would probably provide good noise immunity for the switching. I don't know how much isolation you need, though. I mean, is it critical to have high isolation between FET board and control board? If not, LVDS swichting should work.

Comment: Well, my question could be rephrased into "Do I need isolation for this to work reliably?". So I'm not sure either if isolation is critical. I usually use optocouplers but I just started asking myself if they are always necessary..

Comment: The isolation would be for safety. Sounds like you just need immunity from noise. I have not had to do what you are talking about. But I have had signal integrity problems going from board to board, so I will tell you the things I have found that help. Run each signal with a dedicated ground through twisted pair cable. In other words, each signal / ground pair is treated like a differential signal. This helps a lot. If that is not enough, you may also need to use shielded wire. You can also run each signal through coax. That provides a LOT of immunity from noise pickup.

Comment: Since many answers and suggestions involve adding extra components, then I might just add a gate driving optocoupler, (remove the totem pole) and each OC input LED will be driven by a twisted pair. This should give the best all round solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deal with exactly this situation on a regular basis.  Start by treating the ground connection at each pair of power boards as a star point for the power supply and controller board.  That is: relatively heavy wire between the ground terminals of both power boards.  Another wire from that point to the power supply ground.  One final wire from that point to the ground on the controller card.

What you want to avoid is having the load current cause a shift in ground potential between the logic board and the power boards.  The ground can (will) move around with respect to the power supply ground but so long as the signals between the control and power boards remain constant with respect to each other, you should be good.

Comment: So the controller card is kind of grounded on the power board?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a safe way to avoid loops and noise without using optocouplers?

If you can't maintain a common ground between your boards without creating a ground loop, then some kind of isolation may be required. If you don't want to use optocouplers, you could look at transformer-based isolation. There are devices out there that take care of modulating up an essentially dc control signal to pass it through an isolated connection (for example, from [Maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/sensors-and-sensor-interface/MAX14934.html)).

If you have a roughly common ground between the boards but don't want to connect ground along the same paths as your control connections, then some kind of differential signalling should work. LVDS seems like overkill for any signal switching at less than 50 Mbps, and [current loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_current_loop_interface) seems like overkill for a distance of only 15 cm, but either one ought to be able to withstand a few hundred mV of ground variation between the ends of the connection.

Comment: I was steering away from optocouplers just to avoid adding extra components. But if have to add any device to "cut" the loop then I might just add the optocoupler, seems like the simplest, safest solution, no?

Comment: Or just use logic with sufficient noise immunity. But I don't know how noisy your environment is so it's hard to say for sure which is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said so far, twisted pair to carry the signals should be adequate. You may well want to use serial termination on the lines. I see no reason to expect major problems with pickup issues, and with a 1 KHz PWM frequency you can accept a certain amount of signal degradation. If you want to add insurance, put a certain amount of low-pass filtering on the signal inputs, followed by a Schmitt trigger.

Also, your load lines should be twisted pair as well, and if you want to really do things right, use shielded twisted pair, with the shield grounded at the driver end, but not the load end.

Comment: You mean each twisted pair consists of a signal plus a dedicated ground wire for that signal, right?

Comment: You got it. Twisted pair usually has a characteristic impedance of ~100 to ~150 ohms. (Depends on wire gauge, insulation thickness and twist rate) Using a 120 ohm series resistor will typically do fine as long as your input has an impedance of ~1k or more. Impedance matching doesn't have to be perfect for this sort of thing. The twisted ground line will also serve as a half-assed shield and cut down noise pickup.

Comment: If OP is switching his control signal at 1 MHz or less and the connection distance is 15 cm, he really doesn't have to worry about characteristic impedance at all.

Comment: I agree, but it pretty much comes free with twisted pair, so I just thought I'd be thorough.

Comment: @Wesley Lee - please see also my edited answer.

Comment: What do you mean by serial termination?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla034b/snla034b.pdf